# sqlplus format output

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

What is the sql code to print 'Query' if the data in field = 'Q'?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!

An example out of the box:

```
select decode(dummy, 'X', 'Y') from dual;
```

For your scenario, something like:

```
select decode(mycol, 'Q', 'Query') mycol from mytable;
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Preferred option is to use `CASE` because of readability; although, as @Bjarte suggested, `DECODE` can also be used (which I what I do, especially for simple cases). Also, tables have *columns*, not *fields*.

Anyway, `CASE`:

```
SQL> with test (field) as
  2    -- sample data; you already have that and don't type it
  3    (select 'A' from dual union all
  4     select 'Q' from dual union all
  5     select 'B' from dual
  6    )
  7  -- query you need
  8  select field,
  9         case when field = 'A' then 'Answer'
 10              when field = 'Q' then 'Query'
 11              else 'Unknown'
 12         end as result
 13  from test;

F RESULT
- -------
A Answer
Q Query
B Unknown

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks to all the help I received.